# Error upgrading Grails from 2.1.1 to 2.4.3: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopInfrastructureBean

Tags: grails, spring-security

I was upgrading my grails application from version 2.1.1 to 2.4.3 but i got the error info as below:

```
| Compiling 405 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
General error during conversion: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopInfrastructureBean

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopInfrastructureBean
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1083)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1061)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:583)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:561)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:538)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:517)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.runCompiler(Groovyc.java:1161)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:1212)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.Grailsc.compile(Grailsc.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:827)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:319)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:264)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:147)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:203)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
...
...
...
...
...
org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavaAwareCompilationUnit$1.call(JavaAwareCompilationUnit.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1047)
    ... 565 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:175)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:147)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader.loadClass(GrailsRootLoader.java:51)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 589 more

1 error
```

Build Config file:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5"
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        inherits true

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
        compile "javax.mail:mail:1.4.3"
        runtime "org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.6.RELEASE" 
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.0"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        compile ":cache:1.1.8"
        compile ":mail:1.0.7"
        compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
        compile ":searchable:0.6.9"
        compile ":yui:2.8.2.1"
    }
}
```

I almost updated most of the plugins to the latest version, e.g. `:spring-security-core:2.0-RC4`

I also found an issue in grails's official jira, which describe the same problem as mine:
https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYUI-62

I don't know if it's still a bug which is not solved yet?

Answer (score 2):

Since your BuidConfig.groovy doesn't contains grails.project.dependency.resolver = 'maven' I presume Grails falls back to good old 'ivy'.
I had the ame issue and had to provide manually those 2 dependencies in order to fix this issue: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11184

compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.9.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.9.RELEASE'

Answer (score 0):

For me, upgrading from Grails 2.2.4 to Grails 2.4.2 created a similar error message.

My solution was to add to BuildConfig.groovy, the following "dependencies" section:

```
    dependencies {
    runtime 'org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.5.RELEASE'
    runtime 'org.springframework:spring-expression:4.0.5.RELEASE'
}
```