# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopInfrastructureBean

Tags: java, spring, maven, grails

I have a project done in Grails 2.4.3 and when I try to refresh dependencies I receive the next error:

```html
    |Loading Grails 2.4.3
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
..........
|Compiling 210 source files  [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
General error during conversion: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopInfrastructureBean
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopInfrastructureBean
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1083)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1061)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
 at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:61)
 at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3_closure8_closure9.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
 at _GrailsCompile.withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile.groovy:68)
 at _GrailsCompile.this$4$withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
 at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:60)
 at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3_closure8.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
 at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
 at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
 at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
 at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.profile(BaseSettingsApi.java:342)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
 at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
 at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1074)
 at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1253)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1209)
 at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
 at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1272)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1166)
 at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
 at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
 at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:57)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
 at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
 at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
 at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1272)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1166)
 at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
 at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
 at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
 at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
 at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
 at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:44)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
 at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
 at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
 at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
 at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
 at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1152)
 at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1272)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1166)
 at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
 at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
 at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
 at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
 at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
 at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
 at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
 at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
 at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
 at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
 at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
 at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:809)
 at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
 at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
 at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:780)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:572)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:471)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:415)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:379)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:226)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:236)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:264)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopInfrastructureBean
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.oldFindClass(RootLoader.java:171)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:143)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader.loadClass(GrailsRootLoader.java:51)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:655)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:523)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:183)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:168)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:124)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveToOuter(ResolveVisitor.java:617)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:269)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1159)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:142)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavaAwareCompilationUnit$1.call(JavaAwareCompilationUnit.java:67)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1047)
 ... 348 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean
 at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:175)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:147)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader.loadClass(GrailsRootLoader.java:51)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
 ... 372 more
1 error
```

I tried the solution of this link [1. solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316734/error-upgrading-grails-from-2-1-1-to-2-4-3-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org) but when I use it I get this:

> compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.9.RELEASE' compile 'org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.9.RELEASE'

But when I try to refresh dependencies again I receive the next error:

```html
> Error |
Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.9.RELEASE
- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.9.RELEASE

> ==== mavenCentral: tried
   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.2.9.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.2.9.RELEASE.zip
  [FAILED     ] org.springframework#spring-expression;3.2.9.RELEASE!spring-expression.zip:  (0ms)
> ==== mavenCentral: tried
   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.2.9.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.2.9.RELEASE.zip
  [FAILED     ] org.springframework#spring-expression;3.2.9.RELEASE!spring-expression.zip:  (0ms)
```

when I check the links it tells me: 404 Not Found

In the page of maven: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.2.9.RELEASE/ 
the file `spring-aop-3.2.9.RELEASE.zip` doesn't exist.

I tried with

> compile "org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.3.RELEASE" 
>     compile 'org.springframework:spring-expression:4.1.3.RELEASE'

but I get the same error.

Comment: may be this is useful (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23596293/2749470)

Comment: Have you tried to inserti this line: grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
to your BuildConfig.

Comment: I am using rails.project.dependency.resolver = "ivy".. I tray to use "maven" but i get a error: "Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1, I configure my proxy but nothing :(